# Setting font for collection of labels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `nameLabel` and I can set the font as

```
 @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
 nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)
```

Is there a way, I can do same for collection of labels at once,

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionNameLabels: [UILabel]!
```

Comment: I don't think  you can do it at once since this is array type. so need to iterate.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it

Comment: Use a loop to iterate and assign font for each label. I don't think there is any shortcut for this.

Comment: Thats correct, I was thinking if there is any shortcut that I dont know of

Comment: if you want to set the same font for all your labels you can create an extension on UILabel and set the font there then use it instead of UILabel like: ```@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: CustomUILabel!```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change font of all labels which is created from xib or storyboard in your app, you can use

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)
```

But if you only want to change font of `collectionNameLabels`, as @Sivajee Battina said, i think you have to use a loop to change font for each label.

```
for label in self.collectionNameLabels {
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing as above, but it changes only the first selected label and remaining labels are same, maybe we should use forEach

Comment: @Coder221 using `forEach` and my above way is same. Make sure your `@IBOutlet` is `[UILabel]!` not `UILabel!`. You should check connections again. This above code works fine with me.

Comment: Yes, looks like bug in XCode, we have to drag all labels one by one to connect them to collection.

Comment: Of course, when using collection of labels, you have to drag all labels one by one to connect them to collection. Anyway, congratulation, you fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it more than once, it might be useful to create property for that.

```
var labelFont: UIFont! { didSet { labels.forEach { $0.font = labelFont } } }
```

and in `viewDidLoad` or after set the font:

```
labelFont = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

property observer.

@IBOutlet weak var collectionNameLabels: [UILabel]! {

```
didSet{
  for nameLabel  in collectionNameLabels{
    nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)
  }
}
```

}